# The following SDK components were not installed: Android Support Repository, Android SDK Tools and Google Repository

Tags: android, sdk

I'm trying to install Android Studio and I'm getting this error

"The following SDK components were not installed: Android Support Repository, Android SDK Tools, and Google Repository"

Also, when I try to open new Android Studio project I get this

"Your Android SDK is missing, out of date, or is missing templates. You can configure your SDK via Configure | Project Defaults | Project Structure | SDKs"

I don't really know what to do about this so any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please be informed that if you are connecting to the internet from within one of the embargoed countries such as Iran, then you have to use VPN in order to be able to download these components.That is due to the fact that downloading SDK components requires connecting to some Google servers which are not available for people in such embargoed countries according to some USA's government rules.